# CollapsingToolbarLayout not collapsing when softkeyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a layout that I use for my toolbars;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/expanded_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/expanded_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And I use this in my layouts as;

```
<com.dan.finance.ui.ExpandedToolbar
    android:id="@+id/expandable_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:toolbarNavColor="?attr/NavigationIconColor"
    app:toolbarNavIcon="?attr/NavigationUpArrow"
    app:toolbarTitle="My Finances"
    app:toolbarTitleColor="?attr/NavigationTitleColor"/>
```

And below this in most of my layouts I have a nested scrollview, my problem is on layouts where the content shouldn't scroll by default, opening the soft keyboard allows the content to scroll using adjustResize, but my toolbar doesn't react to this and collapse as it should.

The full code for my layout is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <com.dan.finance.ui.ExpandedToolbar
                android:id="@+id/expandable_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:toolbarNavColor="?attr/NavigationIconColor"
                app:toolbarNavIcon="?attr/NavigationUpArrow"
                app:toolbarTitle="My Finances"
                app:toolbarTitleColor="?attr/NavigationTitleColor"/>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/expandable_toolbar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:text="Finances"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text"                       
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/details"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DETAILS TODO"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView                                                      android:id="@+id/finances_list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/details"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_see_all"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="See All"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/finances_list"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This layout as a whole doesn't scroll on large devices, but may scroll on smaller devices/future releases so I believe this may be where my problem lies but I've tried quite a few different things and nothing has come up. I've also tried programatically expanding and collapsing the toolbar using

```
mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(expand, true);
```

but this doesn't animate the layout I'm assuming because it's not in a scrolling layout because there's no content to bring up maybe?

Comment: It would be helpful to look at _ExpandedToolbar_. Can you post it

Comment: @Cheticamp ExpandedToolbar is the top snippet

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't _ExpandedToolbar_ a custom view? I am trying to understand how the top snippet is actually added to the layout. I think posting the code for _ExpandedToolbar_ would help.

Comment: Yes, the code at the top is in a custom view called ExpandedToolbar

Comment: Can you post that custom view? _ExpandedToolbar.java_ or _ExpandedToolbar.kt_?

Comment: It's java but I don't have it on the laptop I'm on sadly, it's on my work laptop which I won't have until monday. I'll try the suggested answer below on monday as he seems to have figured it out :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*AppBarLayout* must be a direct child of *CoordinatorLayout* for scrolling and collapsing of the layout to work as you expect. (See [*AppBarLayout documentation*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout).)

> This view depends heavily on being used as a direct child within a CoordinatorLayout. If you use AppBarLayout within a different ViewGroup, most of it's functionality will not work.

Here is what your layout looks like as currently coded. (This is from the *Layout Inspector*.)

[image]

As you can see, *AppBarLayout* is not a direct child of *CoordinatorLayout* but is a child of *ExpandedToolbar* which is, in itself, an *AppBarLayout*.

To fix this, you will need to change  *expanded_toolbar.xml* to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true">-->

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/expanded_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/expanded_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <!--</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->
</merge>
```

As you can see, I have removed *AppBarLayout* by commenting it out. Now, when we run the app, we see the following hierarchy:

[image]

Here, you can see that *ExpandedToolbar* which is really an *AppBarLayout* is a direct child of the *CoordinatorLayout*. This works. Here is a visual. I didn't implement the entire custom layout - just enough for demo purposes.

[image]

Here is the updated main layout:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <com.example.customviewtoolbar.ExpandedToolbar
            android:id="@+id/expandable_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:toolbarNavColor="?attr/NavigationIconColor"
            app:toolbarNavIcon="?attr/NavigationUpArrow"
            app:toolbarTitle="My Finances"
            app:toolbarTitleColor="?attr/NavigationTitleColor" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="32dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/finances"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="56dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/details"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DETAILS TODO"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/finances_list"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/details" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_see_all"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="See All"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/finances_list"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As a side note, I removed the anchor-related tags and `android:fillViewport="true"` from the *NestedScrollView* since they are not really needed and prevented the layout inspector from working.

You could always just not use the custom view, but I assume that you want it for convenience.

Here is the mock-up of `ExpandedToolbar` that I used for demo purposes.

**ExpandedToolbar.java**

```
public class ExpandedToolbar extends AppBarLayout {
    public ExpandedToolbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ExpandedToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.MyToolbar,
                0, 0);

        try {
            String title = a.getString(R.styleable.MyToolbar_toolbarTitle);
            ((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.expanded_toolbar)).setTitle(title);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.expanded_toolbar, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used code lines are below in the xml file and it worked this way with both softkeyboard is visible and gone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expanded_collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/expanded_toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_layout"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/title"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingStart="32dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                        android:text="Finances"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="56dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/details"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="DETAILS TODO"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/finances_list"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/details"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:id="@+id/button_see_all"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="See All"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/finances_list"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also you can check in your activity AppBarLayout collapse/expand process with this listener:

```
appbar_layout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
            override fun onOffsetChanged(p0: AppBarLayout?, p1: Int) {
                if (Math.abs(p1) - appbar_layout.totalScrollRange == 0) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Collapsed")
                } else {
                    Log.d("tag", "Expanded")
                }
            }
        })
```

I think it cause because of you're using AppBarLayout in a custom xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` end use only `adjustResize`. should be work

Comment: Nope, this didn't work, I've tried most combinations of removing and adding stuff like that in to not success, my activity it also adjustResize only.